# Check from the server if Android device is online

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

**tl;dr** How to find out from a server if Android device is online or not at any given time?

I have an app which needs an Internet connection at all times to make reservations. User can also make reservations independently, from a website.

However, if Internet connection on Android device is gone (edge case) - I would still like that device continues operate offline (and making reservations locally, offline) while website will stop accepting reservations - because Android device is no longer connected to an Internet and there could happen all kinds of sync errors.

In other words, Android device offline reservations have advantage over a website reservations.

So after Internet connection is retrieved on a device, website will continue operate properly.

**Suggested solution**

I thought about some solution which could include sending a push from a server to device and waiting for a response (HTTP call to some endpoint) in some reasonable time-period. If response doesn't come back - device is offline, otherwise it's online. Any other, more robust, suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't it be far better for you to come up with a more robust protocol and avoid "all kinds of sync errors" in the first place?

Comment: How could I do that? Requirements are that user can make reservation online (website) & an operator can make it from a device (offline or online). Both user and operator must know (before making actual reservation) which slots are available/open. It would be easy to require that if there is no internet-connection on device, reservations are not possible - however that can't be the case.

Comment: "How could I do that?" -- um, by programming. After all, you need to do this anyway. Devices go on and offline very frequently, and Web browsers are not immune to problems. According to your plan, if you are able to determine that the device is online at time `T`, then you expect the whole world will stop in its tracks, to ensure that the device will remain online (and the Web browser will have no problems) until time `T+X` when all the work is complete. That is simply unrealistic. If that means that a change is needed to your "requirements", so be it.

Comment: Now, there has been plenty of work done on synchronization algorithms. One approach is to say that the reservation is not fully "real" until both sides have done their work. This tends to require that resources (e.g., "slots") are put in a "pending" state while the transaction is in progress, so nobody else can poach those resources while that is going on. It also usually involves some sort of timeout, so an abandoned transaction is eventually cleaned up and the resources moved back out of "pending" into "free" states.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do but use some Agent runs on Android and notifies the server that its on.

Other way, more complicated is to use "Push notification" ([Meteor](http://meteorserver.org/) technology server side, for example).

*Something about server side cron-job:*

Stand alone process that run over all clients in data base, lets say every 1 day, and compares for each client last "im alive" meassage (request) with current time.

If difference equals lets say 1 week, sets client status to "Zombie".

Comment: The problem with that approach is that user can arrive on a website and make a reservation between Agent calls (online -> offline). So timeline would be: device is online -> notifies server -> device is offline -> reservation is made on the device in offline mode -> user makes reservation online. Potential collision can occur.

Comment: Not at all, create policy for server (some cron job as service) that if client didn't notify you, lets say, during 1 week - update DB for client as zombie. Im sure you record in database all clients request time stamp